# JSON object to PHP associative array

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am building an array in JS as such:

```
       var slots = {}; 

                $(".taken").each(function(item) {

                    var key = $(this).attr("id");
                    slots[key] = "<?php echo $_SESSION['alias']; ?>";

                }); 

                var json = JSON.stringify(slots);
                var date = "<?php echo $_GET['date']; ?>"
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                     url: "controllers/dutyupdate2.php",
                    data:{ array : json, date:  date },
                success : function(response){
                        console.log (response)
                    }//end success
                });//end ajax
```

In my PHP script I am posting to, I need to decode it to match the following format:

```
array( 'D1P'=>"JohnC" , 'D6E' => "JohnC")
```

I get:

```
Array(
    [D2E] => JohnC
    [D6E] => JohnC
    [D3BU] => JohnC
)
```

No matter how I decode the array, I get an indexed array with my key as the index.
Am I building the array incorrectly in the JS code or decoding incorrectly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how you are decoding......you can use json_decode($data,TRUE);

Comment: "I get an indexed array with my key as the index" - and what exactly do you *want*?

Comment: I don't understand how those 2 array differ (the one you get, the one you want)

Comment: never echo php data directly into a Javascript context. one JS meta-character in that php data and you've killed the entire JS code block. **ALWAYS** use json_encode(), e.g. `<?php echo json_encode($var) ?>` so you always produce something syntactically valid.

Comment: My PDO class will update with the assoc array in the format: array( 'D1P'=>"JohnC", but not with : [D4E] => JohnC....thats where I am having the issue, in converting the key to an assoc key..

Comment: @Marc B, Thanks, I see what you mean...

Comment: So is there no way to get the array into the format I am looking for?

Comment: or maybe parse the array in the PHP script?

Comment: Isn't it just easier to use object `slots.key` instead of array `slots[key]` for json?

Comment: @Jjames: The array *is* in the format you are looking for!  `print_r(array( 'D1P'=>"JohnC" , 'D6E' => "JohnC"))`.

Comment: @Bondye: Not if `key` is a variable.

Comment: Yes, I thought so from the beginning, IT was entirely my F-UP...:), I appreciate the answers not being to harsh...thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the format you want, just displayed differently. See this PHP code to verify

```
$a = array( 'D1P'=>"JohnC" , 'D6E' => "JohnC");
print_r($a);
```

this gives

```
Array
(
    [D1P] => JohnC
    [D6E] => JohnC
)
```

as output. So, there's no need to try or search anything different.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I am not sure where I was FUBAR ing it up, but it is correct, I thank you for your time